# in Rails, make assets:precompile output the list of files it has precompiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In Rails, how do I output list of assets compiled for assets pipeline by `rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it seems there is no way to print out list of assets compiled by asset pipeline

Answer (score 4):

This is 2 years later, but I just found this question asked another time and figured it out. You can do weird things with `Sprockets`!

```
Rails.application.assets.each_logical_path(*Rails.application.config.assets).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `manifest.yml` file in your assets directory after you have precompiled your assets.  You can find the directory it resides in by checking `config.assets.prefix`.  You can change the location by setting  `config.assets.manifest = '/path/to/some/other/location'`

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5, on console:

```
Rails.application.config.assets[:precompile]
```